# How to find commit by tag name

Tags: git

I am just trying to find the way to show tags in the output of

```
git log
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Your question title doesn't seem to correspond to the text.

Comment: Sorry. The reason is a my bad english :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git log --decorate
```

This decorates commits with tag and branch names.